# Read a txt line by line in a batch file

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

Here is my problem. I have a txt file with 100 different video names (examples):

```
abc.mpg
def.mpg
ghi.mpg
xyz.mpg
```

I want to process those videos one by one using some commands and put the results into a folder with the same name (without the extension):

```
command1 abc.mpg
command2 abc.mpg
move results .\abc
```

My question is how can I perform the above iteration with a for loop within a batch file.

Answer (score 23):

The command is FOR with /F parameter like this

```
FOR /F %i in (yourFile.txt) DO yourcommand %i
```

this reads a line at a time from the text file and insert the value into the %i argument
Then call the command specified after the DO keyword (the command could be another batch with the copy or move operations required)

Comment: If file names in the list may contain spaces, add `"delims="` (or `"tokens=*"`) just after `/F`: `FOR /F "delims=" %i IN …`.

Comment: Note that if you put double-quotes around `yourFile.txt`, the `FOR` will loop over that text rather than reading the file. cmd is so confusing. The docs at [ss64 FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) go into greater detail on it all.