# BATCH: Convert each line of Txt file to a system variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, process, line

i have an, at first sight, easy problem.

I have to configure an SAS controller with 1-4 disks attached.
Therefore i have to know in which slot the drives are attached.
This i could solve, the result is a text file containing min 1 and max 4 entries.

Now i want to read each line of this file and convert them to system variables.
This was my try:

```
    for /f %%i in (disp.txt) do (
    set slot_1=%%i
    set slot_2=%%j
    set slot_3=%%k
    set slot_4=%%l
)
```

The result is this

```
Slot_1=3
Slot_2=%j
Slot_3=%l
Slot_4=%l
```

What i´m doing wrong?

P.S.:
yes, i found [BATCH/CMD: Print each line of a .txt into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303096/batch-cmd-print-each-line-of-a-txt-into-a-variable) - but its not the same

P.P.S.:
the disp.txt looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason what you have won't work is because `FOR /F ... IN (filename) DO ...` will operate on each line of the file (splitting it into records) and assigning the first record to `%i`. So, `%i` will be set to 1, 2, 3, 4 (your example of dist.txt), once for each time through the loop.

You can use variable values in the name of the variable being assigned to (though to do so in a FOR loop requires enabling delayed variable expansion, look for the `!` instead of `%` to access the variable).

This modified version of your script might do what you want:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET IDX=1
FOR /F %%i IN (disp.txt) DO (
    SET "slot_!IDX!=%%i"
    SET /A IDX+=1
)
```

It will work for any number of lines in disp.txt.